How to prove Tukey-Cooley FFT
I am struggling to understand 2 points of the derivation of the Tukey-Cooley FFT. The wikipedia article spells it out for the most part, but once it gets to the equation that originally is an equality for all of $X_k$:

I'm tripped up by where it says:

"Note that the equalities hold for $k=0,...N-1$, but the crux is that $E_k$ and $O_k$ are calculated in this way for $k = 0,...,\frac{N}{2}-1$ only"

Immediately after it then claims:

"Thanks to the periodicity of the complex exponential, $X_{k + \frac{N}{2}}$ is also obtained from $E_k$ and $O_k$"


I don't understand how these points are justified.
For 1, it seems unreasonable to me that you can use an equality to derive a relationship, but then wave away the second half of the components of that equality.
For 2, the Fourier transform itself is only supposed to be periodic over the interval of [0,N] so I don't see how we can make the leap that these small DFT's can be used for the second half of the output terms.
